# Share incoming streaming video

Tags: linux, windows, media-server

My wife and I work in different parts of the house, and we frequently listen to the same podcast(s) at the same time - both of us streaming them live from the web, in parallel. At the end of each day, we have double-streamed hours of duplicate content.

How can I configure things so that only one of us streams the podcast, and the other can access the stream?

Ideally, I would like for us each to see what the other person is streaming and have the option to tap into that stream - watch/listen to what they are listening to.

I have a spare machine sitting beside me that I can re-configure as a Linux box (I am mid-intermediate level in Linux), but unsure where to go for the media server recipe, and which recipe would best match my requirements. However, if there is a way for each Windows machine to "publish/serve" streaming content that would be even better.

Both my wife and I are on Windows 7 machines.

Advice / suggestions / links appreciated.

Comment: Do you pay for your data by the byte? If not, I can't see the point of going to all that effort. Your call, of course, but it seems a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: There are a few devices such as Amazon Echo devices that support multi-room streaming, but chances are they stream individually just the same as you do. The only real way to do this and download once is to set up one machine as a media server using something like [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/), download the podcast yourself, add the podcast to your media, and then use the "watch together" feature. It's a lot of faff to save a minimal amount of bandwidth.

Comment: Not worth the effort.  The technology you speak of is called "multicast" and has been around since the 90s.. but is a PITA for the scenario you describe.  See [this](https://peakdrive.com/how-to-use-vlc-media-player-to-stream-multicast-video/)